# ¿Como se reduce el tamaño de una imagen antes de guardarla con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Actualmente tengo la siguiente función, que guarda foto:

```
     $('#guardar_saca_foto').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            saca_foto();
        });



       function saca_foto() {
        var fileUpload = $("#sacar_foto").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;

        // Create FormData object
        var fileData = new FormData();
        fileData.append("numero", numero_global);
        // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            //var peso=files[i].size;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Devolucion/GuardarImagenes_Devol/',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fileData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    recargar_listado_fotos(numero_global);
                    mostrar_msj_success('Foto Guardadas Correctamente');
                } else if (data == "-1") {
                    $("#ajax_loader").hide();
                    mostrar_msj_error("error: El tiempo de sesión ha expirado");
                } else if (data == "2") {
                    $("#ajax_loader").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#ajax_loader").hide();
                    mostrar_msj_error("error interno: " + data);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

En el html:

```
<input type="file" name="sacar_foto" id="sacar_foto" class="SubirFoto" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
                            <label for="sacar_foto">
                                <figure><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z" /></svg></figure> <span>Sacar foto...</span>
                            </label>
```

Esta forma de guardar foto, la uso cuando saco una foto con el celular, y resulta que algunos celulares tiene la calidad de foto muy alta, y eso hace que sea pesada. Mi pregunta, existe una forma de reducir el peso, ya que cuando la guardo a binario, no lo puede guardar porque es muy grande.

Voy a colocar el codigo en C# donde uso el controller para guardar foto.

```
 public ActionResult GuardarImagenes_Devol(string numero)
        {
            var retorno = "";
           
                try
                {
                    conexion.conectar();
                    string sql = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var file = Request.Files[i];
                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            string tipo = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                            {
                                byte[] archivo_binario = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                                sql = "INSERT devolimg";
                                sql += " SET numero =@numero";
                                sql += " ,foto =@foto";
                                sql += " ,nombre =@nombre";
                                sql += " ,tipo =@tipo";
                                MySqlCommand datos_foto = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con);
                                datos_foto.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@numero", numero));
                                datos_foto.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@foto", archivo_binario));
                                datos_foto.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@nombre", fileName));
                                datos_foto.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@tipo", tipo));
                                datos_foto.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    retorno = "1";
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                    retorno = error.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexion.cerrar();
                }
                return Json(retorno);
            
        }
```

Si no se puede por jquery en la vista del html, quizás se podrá en C#. ¿Es posible reducir el tamaño y como de una foto?

Desde ya, gracias.
Saludos

Comment: [lo mejor es hacerlo en c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790275/resize-image-which-is-placed-in-byte-array)

Comment: @John, pero como, algun ejemplo?

Comment: esta en el enlase `System.IO.MemoryStream myMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myBytes);
System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
System.Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage .GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
System.IO.MemoryStream myResult = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
newImage.Save(myResult ,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);  //Or whatever format you want.
return  myResult.ToArray();  //Returns a new byte array`.

Comment: @John, gracias funciona, pero me gira la foto, no se porque lo hace, como corrijo eso?